# Why isn't correlation in the description of entangled states just a sign of model information redundancy?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, information

Two entangled particles are described (modeled) such that there may be a correlation between parts of the model.  That is, measuring one of the pair provides information about the other.  Why isn't this just a case of redundancy in the description/model, which, if reformulated to remove it would eliminate the correlation without effecting any predictions?  That is, the model represents some of the same information redundantly.

To make a (perhaps poor) analogy, consider coin toss experiments (to make it concrete, but assume the observer knows nothing about coins per-se and hence we can't know anything about classicality etc). I might construct a model with two binary variables, one labelled 'heads facing up' vs 'tails facing up' and the other 'heads facing down' vs 'tails facing down'.  After running experiments and recording the results, I notice that there is a correlation between the variables (in this case, perfect non-probabilistic anti-correlation).  So, I can deduce my model just has redundancy in representation of information.  I can reformulate it into a new model with a single variable without losing any predictive power.

**How is this different from noting a correlation** (albeit probabilistic and partial) **in the quantum model for an entangled pair** and deducing that there is just redundancy and I can reformulate the model in different terms such that the redundancy (and hence correlation) is eliminated without changing any predictions?

If this were done, would it be just for the specific model for this case of an entangled pair, but still using 'the standard model', or would the standard model itself need to be reformulated (syntax/terminology etc.) without changing its predictions.  (As in, there are near-infinite ways the standard model could be changed - for example, just renaming one particle - a mundane superficial syntactic-only change).

Answer (score 1):

Your viewpoint works for a special case: so-called "perfect correlations".  Those are situations where in fact the redundant measurements are performed.  A specific example: Alice measuring the spin (or polarization) of an entangled particle at an angle of 60 degrees (say), and Bob Alice measuring the spin/polarization) of its entangled partner at the same angle of 60 degrees.  The results are 100% correlated - and therefore completely redundant in the sense you intend.  Your model is often referred to a "realistic" interpretation.

Bell's Theorem was published in the mid 1960's, and demonstrated that in fact the quantum predictions at just about any other pair of angles could not be explained in the manner you describe.  For example: if you measure one of a pair at 0 degrees, and the other at 60 degrees, their correlation is strictly dependent on theta - the difference between the two angles.  It turns out that no predetermined outcomes - as you implicitly imagine - can correctly reproduce the actual correlation statistics for most values of theta (other than the special case of theta=0).  So when theta=60 degrees, the quantum prediction cannot be reproduced by your model's assumptions.

In other words: there are no possible theories using your viewpoint - no matter how ingenious - that will reproduce the full range of quantum predictions.  Of course, if QM is wrong, then all bets are off.  However, this has been tested extensively in the past 40-50 years, and QM passes with flying colors.

I might recommend you follow one of the links below to learn more about Bell, and see a proof (if you need one) of why an entire class of potential explanations is excluded by Bell.  Bell's Theorem is one of the most important when discussing entanglement; without understanding Bell, you will miss out on understanding one of the most interesting sides of Quantum Mechanics.

Original Bell paper (this is actually not a good starting point - the proof is fairly technical):
https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/bell/Bell_On_EPR.pdf

David Mermin, Is the Moon There When Nobody Looks:
https://dokumen.tips/documents/is-the-moon-there-when-nobody-looks-reality-and-the-ecen5345resourcesmermin85bellsthmpdf.html?page=1

Bell's Theorem on Stanford's Plato:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bell-theorem/

All of the above also discuss the important 1935 EPR paper, which is relevant to any discussion of Bell.  The upshot is: realistic interpretations require one to accept the existence of "action at a distance".  But that is a subject best discussed in a different thread.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer.  You say "if you measure one of a pair at 0 degrees, and the other at 60 degrees, their correlation is strictly dependent on theta" - but I don't see how theta dependence changes 
 anything - surely a correlation of any kind implies information redundancy (in any theory).  I'm aware of Bell's theorem and how it rules out non-local hidden variables (but not all hidden variables), but am not an expert. I'll try to understand the proof.  Perhaps information in a hidden variable is being redundantly incorporate into multiple QM variables (conjecture).